# Ally Invest - Charting Display % Change

Tags: stocks

I'm new to Ally Invest and can't seem to find out how to have the chart show the Percentage Change in Price in the selected timeframe.  I was clicking around once and got the little ticker on the right to display it.  But I've had no luck and even tried calling Ally.

Similar to Robinhood.

[image]

Comment: Does it change to % if you add a stock to compare? I know nothing of Ally but I've seen that on other platforms.

Comment: @DStanley OMG Thank you so much.  That did it.